# Why do I get "duplicate" local IP addresses on different interfaces?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networkmanager, iproute

I have two network interfaces(a wireless and an USB dongle) attached to an Ubuntu server and both get the same local IP address. Is there any reason for this or a way to force it assign distinct IP addresses?

Below is the output from `ip addr`(the mac is partially masked):

```
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:16:XXXX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fa16:54ff:fe96:c648/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 58:2c:XXX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5a2c:80ff:fe13:9263/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1  proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100  metric 1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100  metric 9
```

cat  /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#post-up route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0

#auto usb0
#iface usb0 inet dhcp
#post-up route del default dev usb0
```

root@:~# sudo arp-scan -I eth1 -l

```
Interface: eth1, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.1.1 00:0d:87XXX Elitegroup Computer System Co. (ECS)

1 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 1.316 seconds (194.53 hosts/sec). 1 responded
```

root@:~# sudo arp-scan -I wlan0 -l

```
Interface: wlan0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.1.1 e8:cd:2XXX  (Unknown)
192.168.1.101   20:cXXX (Unknown)
```

Comment: 1) can you show /etc/network/interfaces ? 2) eth0 looks unpluged.

Comment: @Archemar  If I manually unplug it and check the external IP address with an internet  service (i.e. getip.com) I get a different IP address  so I can only assume that it's being used and it's the interface used by default as expected if I take  the "metric" from ip route(it has 1; wlan has 9) as good.  /etc/network/interfaces looks good to me.(edited the question)

Comment: If you run Network Manager, does it show hardwired addresses for each of those interfaces, or DHCP?

Comment: @Mark The Method is "Automatic(DHCP)" for both. http://i.imgur.com/8j2fCwo.png

Comment: It's worth to note that even if I restart the interfaces (i.e. unplug them) I still get the same duplication issue.

Comment: Are those two interfaces ultimately connected to the same network? Like, maybe the wireless access point is just bridged to a wired network rather than being a router itself?

Comment: The wireless network is an 3G Dongle too but the computer connects to it only through Wireless so I guess it's not a wired network. The other network(`eth1`) is  connected through the USB port.

Comment: @Mark I've also run  arp-scan(see the updated question)

Comment: It looks like you either have a single router that is on both the wired and wireless networks, or two different routers that are configured with the same network number. Do you know who administers these networks?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick each nic has its own router (builtin in the device) so it's not possible to have the same router on both of them. The networks are "administrated" automatically by NetworkManager[0]. Would be safe to assume that's a bug?   [0] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager

Comment: Ok, I thought it was likely that there were two different routers involved, but couldn't be sure. You may have no choice of IP address with the 3G device. I haven't encountered Ethernet NICs that have a router builtin to the device.  But most wired routers with a builtin DHCP server ought to be configurable at least as far as the ability to specify the network number. Can you tell us the brand and model number of the wired NIC?